# shortest path between all points problem, floyd warshall

Tags: c, shortest-path, dijkstra

> Mr. Rowan plans to make a walking tour
>   of Paris. However, since he is a
>   little lazy, he wants to take the
>   shortest path that goes through all
>   the places he wants to visit. He plans
>   to take a bus to the first place and
>   another one back from the last place,
>   so he is free to choose the starting
>   and ending places. Can you help him?
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input contains the
>   number of places to visit (n). Then,
>   in the following n lines, you find the
>   coordinates of each place to visit.
>   Here is an example:
>
> > 3
> >
> > 132 73
> >
> > 49 86
> >
> > 72 111
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, your program
>   should output one line containing the
>   minimum distance that Mr. Rowan must
>   walk to visit all places assuming that
>   the walking distance from one place to
>   another is the Euclidean distance. The
>   algorithm should output a number in
>   fixed-point notation with exactly 3
>   digits to the right of the decimal
>   point and no leading space. There are
>   at most 12 places to visit. Example
>
> **Example input:**
>
> > 3
> >
> > 132 73
> >
> > 49 86
> >
> > 72 111
>
> **Example output:**
>
> > 104.992

i've been working on this code, for my homework, but i cant make it work, im start wondering if this is the best approach..

the problem is the floyd-warshall function, that does nothing on float **path structure.. dont know why.. path is the same before and after the floydwarshall(path, n, next);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

/*Implementing of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm*/


struct point {
    float x;
    float y;
};


float cost(struct point* a, struct point* b) {

    return sqrt(pow((*a).x - (*b).x, 2) + pow((*a).y - (*b).y, 2));

}


float** f2dmalloc(int n, int m){

    int i;
    float **ptr;

    ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(float *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ptr[i] = calloc(m, sizeof(float));
    }

    return ptr;

}



void floydwarshall(float **path, int n, float ** next){
    int i, j, k;
    float a, b;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                a = path[i][j];
                b = path[i][k] + path[k][j];
                path[i][j] = ((a) < (b) ? a : b);
                next[i][j] = k;

            }
        }
    }

}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{



    int i;
    int j;
    int n;

    float temp;
    float mininum;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    /*
    A 2-dimensional matrix. At each step in the algorithm, path[i][j] is the shortest path
    from i to j using intermediate vertices (1..k−1).  Each path[i][j] is initialized to
    cost(i,j).
    */
    float ** path;
    float ** next;
    struct point* points;

    path = f2dmalloc(n, n);
    next = f2dmalloc(n, n);

    points = malloc(n * sizeof(struct point));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%f %f", &(points[i].x), &(points[i].y));
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            path[i][j] = cost(&points[i], &points[j]);
        }
    }


    temp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mininum = FLT_MAX;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%.3f\t", path[i][j]);
            if (path[i][j] < mininum && path[i][j] != 0){
                mininum = path[i][j];
            }

        }
        printf("\tminimum - %.3f\n", mininum);
        temp += mininum;
    }

    floydwarshall(path, n, next);


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%.3f\t", next[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*
    temp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mininum = FLT_MAX;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%.3f\t", path[i][j]);
            if (path[i][j] < mininum && path[i][j] != 0){
                mininum = path[i][j];
            }

        }
            printf("\tminimum - %.3f\n", mininum);
        temp += mininum;
    }

    printf("%.3f\n", temp);

     */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Floyd-Warshall solves the problem: For each pair of points, find the shortest path joining them. (It needs to join these two points. It doesn't need to do anything else. It will only visit other points if that produces a shorter path.)

In the present case, since you can always go directly from any point to any other, the shortest path is always the direct one: just go from A to B. (Which is why calling `floydwarshall` doesn't change anything.)

But the problem you're trying to solve seems to be the travelling salesman problem: find a path that visits *all* your points and is as short as possible.

These are entirely different problems, and you'll need to do something quite different to solve the problem you've been asked to solve.

Comment: the text is a little confusing but I think it has to be a shortest distance to each point dynamic programming problem. or else the teacher is kind of playing with the kids.

Comment: i need the shortest path possible, but not return to the initial point.. i've seen the travelling salesman problem but in every description it was a computing a closed circuit..

Comment: Could you post more of the problem statement? It might be easier to work out absolutely-for-sure what you're being asked to do if we have a bit more context. For instance, are there examples of the form "given these points, here is a correct answer"? Or any suggestions about what sort of algorithm you should use?

Comment: Mr. Rowan?  As in, William Rowan Hamilton?  Of Hamilton's puzzle?

Comment: Since his problem does not have the requirement that the tour ends where it started, it is not asking for a cycle, and so it is not the TSP. In addition, Floyd Warshall will not visit all the points; it will only visit all the points necessary to go from point A to B with the shortest distance. However, this person wants to visit all the points, and doesn’t care what the end point is, so long as it will accomplish that in the shortest path possible. If there is a shorter path than the TSP solution that doesn’t end where it starts but still visits all points, he’d prefer it.